# If there is an __init__.py file, should there be a __new__.py file?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I am working on a program that is structured in the following way:

```
program/
  base/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    ...
  app1/
    __init__.py
    module11.py
    module12.py
    ...
  app2/
    __init__.py
    module21.py
    module22.py
    ...
  ...
```

Package `base`'s `__init__.py` is used to expose a minimum set of objects collectively required by `app1` and `app2`, like so:

```py
# __init__ file
from module1 import rock, paper
from module2 import scissor
...
```

I understand that when a program implements a class, and when that program is executed, the interpreter calls the class's `__new__` method if it exists, then calls `__init__` method.

My question is this: can packages implement, say, a `__new__.py` file that works in the same way as a class's `__new__` method?  In the case of my program, I would be using such a file to dynamically alter `rock`, `paper`, or `scissor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they can't. The [specification of the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) declares that only `__init__.py` is used in a special manner by the language. Any other file you put in the folder is just a regular file.

The similarities with the `__init__` method in object creation are limited to the name.